# Filters on a Register api Flask | Angular

Tags: python, angular, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Im learning about Flask and Angular and i tried to make a web app, i want to implement a register watching some examples an other things, so im doing one but i want it to do like a filter, the typical filter of the email, a filter that validates that you have a domain and not only pipo123, or validates that there are not numbers in the names.

This is my code:

```
@app.route('/user/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    r_first_name=request.get_json()['first_name']
    r_last_name=request.get_json()['last_name']
    r_email=request.get_json()['email']
    r_password=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(request.get_json()['password']).decode('utf-8')
    result=""
    if user_database_service.if_user_exists(r_email):
        result="user already exists"
        return jsonify({'result': result})
    new_user=LocalUser(first_name=r_first_name, last_name=r_last_name, email=r_email, password=r_password, created=datetime.utcnow())
    added=user_database_service.add_user(new_user)
    if added is True:
        result="user successfully added"
    else:
        result="unable to add"
    return jsonify({'result': result})
```

and this is the user_database_service

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, false
from sqlalchemy import exc

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from user_database_setup import Base, LocalUser

engine=create_engine('sqlite:///users.db')
Base.metadata.bind=engine
DBSession=sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def get_user(r_email):
    session=DBSession()
    q=session.query(LocalUser).filter(r_email == LocalUser.email).first()
    session.close()
    if q:
        resulted_user=LocalUser(id=q.id, first_name=q.first_name, last_name=q.last_name, email=q.email, password=q.password, created=q.created)
        return resulted_user
    else:
        return None

def if_user_exists(r_email):
    session=DBSession()
    q=session.query(LocalUser).filter(r_email == LocalUser.email).first()
    session.close()
    if q is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def add_user(new_user):
    try:
        session=DBSession()
        session.add(new_user)
        session.flush()
        session.commit()
        session.close()
        return True
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
        return False

def get_user(r_email):
    session=DBSession()
    q=session.query(LocalUser).filter(r_email == LocalUser.email).first()
    session.close()

    if q:
        result=LocalUser(id=q.id, first_name=q.first_name, last_name=q.last_name, email=q.email, password=q.password, created=q.created)
        return result
    else:
        return None
```

I apreciate all your tips! Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if an email adress is valid using regular expressions `regex`. A `regex` is a string that specifies some rules that you want to check.

A quick intro to `regex`

- `[a-z]` is for checking for a character between a and z
- `[0-9]` is for checking for digits from 0 to 9
  then you can check for strings that have a letter followed by a hashtag then by a number with this `regex`: `[a-z]#[0-9]`.
  Some strings that satisfy this `regex` are `a#4`, `s#1`.

This way you can make a `regex` for emails, and checking if a username does not start with a number

Python library `re` is quite easy to use for these purposes

Here are some useful sites

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Hope that helps!